# Using the Didn't take something

Tags: word-usage, idioms, phrases

**Situation**: A person (male) says something to a (female) aged 50+ both. The female ignores it. I could see from her face that she didn't take what he said in a good way.

Can I say this: "*She didn't take it positively*"?  or "*She didn't take it nicely*"?

Or is there a better way to express the same

Comment: "She didn't take it very well."

Answer (score 1):

In this kind of context, "*take it*" refers to the *manner* in which information, advice, feedback etc was *received*.

Neither 'positively' nor 'nicely' are good adjectives for describing that manner.

You might say:

> She didn't *see it positively*.

or

> She didn't *react nicely*.

But if you want to refer to the manner in which she received 'it', the most idiomatic way would be to say:

> She didn't take it well.

or

> She took is badly.